# .htaccess redirect of specific php request

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I would like to use .htaccess to redirect the following request:

```
http://www.oldwebsite.com/?feed=rss2
```

to my new website:

```
http://www.newwebsite.com/feed/
```

Is there any simple way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to capture the `QUERY_STRING` in the Condition:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^feed=
RewriteRule .+ http://www.newwebsite.com/feed [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Not sure your answer is fully answering the question: I want to redirect to the feed on a new domain: http://www.oldwebsite.com/?feed=rss2 --> http://www.newwebsite.com/feed/